# It is possible to have zh_HK not use values-zh-rTW strings?

Tags: android, localization, chinese-locale

I want my android app to display chinese (using the zh-rTW strings) when the device is in zh_TW and display the default language (english in this case) for zh_HK. Is that possible?

I am testing on Android 7.1.1, only 1 locale in the setting: zh_HK. The app has multiple strings.xml, which contains zh_rTW. When I open the app, I can see everything in zh.

Comment: AFAIK, that should be the default behavior, for Android 6.0 and older, and for Android 7.0+ when the user has only chosen one locale. A device configured for `zh-rTW` would use `zh-rTW` or `zh` strings, but not `zh-rHK`. If the user of an Android 7.0+ device tells their device that they would like `zh-rTW` or `zh-rHK` locales, then Android would use `zh-rHK` along with `zh-rTW` and `zh` strings. If this is not the behavior that you are seeing, please provide a [mcve] along with details of what device you are trying and how that device is configured for locales.

Comment: Yes. Don't provide the `values-zh-rHK` folder. Put your English strings in `values` (which will be the default fall-in folder) and also provide your zh_rTW strings in `values-zh-rTW`. This way, Hong Kong users will see the strings in English (I still must understand why do you want it so). And Taiwanese users will see the strings in zh_TW.

Comment: The reason why is because the HK content are all in english, so it makes no sense to display the UI in zh. However, I just tried and it does not work. There is only one value-zh in the project which is zh-rTW, and the only language setting on my phone is T.Chinese Hong Kong, yet I am still seeing the whole UI in zh

Comment: `There is only one value-zh in the project` ... So what? add the missing `value-zh-rTW` and put your Taiwanese strings in. Delete the `values-zh` folder and put the English strings in `values`. Or say it all and tell us you're trying to hack someone else's app... ;)

Comment: Sorry, my english is not so good. the project does not contain value-zh. it contains value-zh-rTW, value-ja-JP, etc. there is no value-zh-{anything else} in the project. and no, i am not hacking someone else's app ;;;;;;)

Comment: `the only language setting on my phone is T.Chinese Hong Kong` Then there's not much you can do. Apart of providing your app with an on-the-fly language setting. Which can be saved in a preference, from a list. Then, on the next run you read the preference, set the language and update the UI. I know, it sounds more difficult than it actually is.

Answer (score 2):

if only for display you can take the locale "zh_HK" and change it to "en_US" whenever someone choose this language or your device change it.I think it is the same way you create a button that changes the language. You take the default locale and change it to the one you want.If i understood the question correct.